PostgreSQL / MariaDB, isolation differences
The following sequences of SQL statements are executed on two different connections to the same database.
1: START TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
1: UPDATE Person SET LastLogin=NOW() WHERE IDPerson=1
[...paused...]

2: START TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
2: INSERT INTO Log (FKIDPerson, Hash) VALUES (1, '95baa69a26a95db2');
2: COMMIT

[...continued...]
1: COMMIT

Column Log.FKIDPerson references the primary key Person.IDPerson (ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE). This runs in PostgreSQL without trouble. I am trying to port it to MariaDB for a customer (only difference in this minimum example is a slight syntax change in opening the transaction), but the INSERT statement of the second connection runs into a lock.
I need exactly this sequence of statements and - for reasons beyond the scope of this small example - I need them nested. How can I instruct MariaDB that this is not a problem (changing the isolation level all the way down to READ UNCOMMITED does not help)?
Update:
While moving LastLogin into a separate table does fix the current problem it cures the symptom not the cause; Log must be writable in separate transactions; I might end up in future versions with moving many or all attributes of Person to a separate table.
How about breaking up the referential integrity here (only in the MySQL version) and replacing it with a trigger on Person deleting obsolete Log records? It feels horrible to me, but after all the only real risk are some stale records which - in case - could easily be found and cleaned. Any opinions?

what does select version(); show?  I don't see anything in the doc about that start transaction syntax.

seems like keeping updateable info like LastLogin in a separate table (with its own FKIDPeron) would fix this

@ysth: 10.11.6-MariaDB-0+deb12u1 . In MariaDB the opening has to be split into START TRANSACTION and SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE, but I did not want to duplicate the whole bunch for this mere syntactical difference.

yeah, I don't see anything better to do than have separate PersonID and PersonData tables.  you could make a Person view joining them to limit the number of queries you need to change, but cleaner just to change everything

oh, just saw the update; not sure what additional problems you are thinking of.  if nothing changes Person except inserts and deletes, I don't see anything to worry about.  removing the foreign key constraint from Log would work too.  imo a table called Log shouldn't be deleted from except by age anyway, but a trigger could do it.

The exclusive row lock on T1 is inconsiderate as to which columns are updated, and hence blocking T2 until a point of commit where the PersonID can be validated to exist.

Would it work to combine those into a single transaction?  Or use a TRIGGER?
